# Problems during the build

Tags: webpack

I have these errors when i try to compile with webpack :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/maxim/test/test/node_modules/destroy'
 @ ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 14:17-30
 @ ./node_modules/koa/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/koa/lib/application.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/koa/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/maxim/test/test/node_modules/koa/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/koa/lib/request.js 9:12-26
 @ ./node_modules/koa/lib/application.js
 @ ./src/index.js
```

here is my webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require("path");

    module.export =  {
      entry: "./src/index.js",
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
      },
    };
```

what can I do ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that webpack is trying to bundle koajs for the browser, which isn't possible. See the Github issue below.

https://github.com/koajs/koa/issues/1013

Specifying `target: "node"` in your webpack config object should solve the problem.

Comment: well I dont find any solution :(